# How can i pause program execution in the scenario given in description?

Tags: java, android

I am making an android app. Here's what I want: User clicks a button, button text changes to "xyz", and then the program waits for 1 second and then the button text changes to "abc".If I use Thread.sleep(1000) then the program does stop for a second but the button text doesn't change to "xyz" before the program goes to sleep.

Comment: You should learn how the threads are working, more precicly, the GUI threads. You are not release the UI threads (with the sleep) so the process doesn't have the time to update the text. You should use an other thread for that

Comment: What @AxelH said and also check out Android Handlers https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Handler` to achieve this. Using `postdelayed` method you can do this. Below is the code to do this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setText("xyz");   // text changed to xyz
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        button.setText("abc");   //text changed to abc after 1 second.
                    }
                },1000);
            }
        });
```